# I am trying to use $resource for fetching data from ASP.NET webApi but it is not working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[image: You can see the errors in the image]

I am new to webapi as well as angular and cannot find a proper solution to this, please help me out and if you can please suggest me some good resources to learn about this topic.

productResource.js file:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('Random')
    .factory('productResource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:60208/");
    });
});
```

T.js file

```
var app = angular.module("JobsApp", []);
app.controller("JobController", function($scope,$http,productResource)
{
    $scope.Jobs = productResource.query();
});
```

Index.cshtml file:

```
<div ng-app="JobsApp">
    <div ng-controller="JobController">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Job Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Minimum</th>
                <th>Maximum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="j in Jobs">
                <td>{{j.job_id}}</td>
                <td>{{j.job_desc}}</td>
                <td>{{j.min_lvl}}</td>
                <td>{{j.max_lvl}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an Angular 2 question, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `ngResource` to you module to get it working. Like

```
(function () {
    "use strict";    
    angular.module('Random',['ngResource'])
    .factory('productResource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:60208/");
    });
});
```

**Update**

Your URL seems to be incorrect too. You need to create a `WebAPI controller` class at backend to communicate, It should be RESTful like `/User/jobs`.

Further please ensure that you have added `angular-resource.js` in your app.

Comment: whats not working, ? do you get same error or new error. ? further few tryout : use same module name for factory register `JobsApp` ,  and 
access data like : `productResource.query(function(data){
 $scope.Jobs = data;
})`

Comment: Yes, still the same error. Can you give me an example of fetching data from any service using $resource in mvc?

Comment: I guess your implementaion of backend is not proper, as your url says it, Please check [this section](http://vmsdurano.com/asp-net-5-jump-start-to-angularjs-with-mvc-6-web-api/#addingwebapicontroller) only not whole page. :)  and also I've attached link to fiddle for demo. See the included scripts in fiddler and try to connect your code with it.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyw4aaz8/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html

make your code like below..

```js
var app = angular.module("JobsApp",["ngResource"]);
app.controller("JobController",['$scope','productResource', function($scope,  productResource){
   productResource.query(function(value) {
  $scope.Jobs=value;
    //console.log(value);
 });
}]);

app.factory('productResource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="JobsApp">
<div ng-controller="JobController">
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Job Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Minimum</th>
                <th>Maximum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="job in Jobs">
                <td>{{job.id}}</td>
                <td>{{job.title}}</td>
                <td>{{job.userId}}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```